# Cannot import csv file into R

Tags: r, csv, readfile

I'm trying to import the csv files from my working directory. There are 3 such files, but for some reason R insists on recognizing only one of them. I can't determine what the pattern is, and if the recognized file is moved out of the folder then nothing is recognized. Here is my code:

```
files = list.files(pattern="*\\.csv$")
```

Each of the files is for sure a csv file which I confirmed by inspecting the "Type" column in the windows folder navigator, and to be safe I also saved a copy as CSV and still had the same problem.

Is there an aspect to this I'm unaware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `files = list.files(pattern=".csv")`

Comment: Hey @Kevin. I had tried that with no effect. I've tried several permutations of the regex pattern, none of which worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `getwd()` and make sure the working directory is pointing to the directory with the files. The above works properly. Also this only gets the file names it does not read them.

Comment: Hey. I know that I'm in the right working directory because it does recognize one of the files in that directory (I also set it manually). And I'm only looking for the names here.

Comment: The above works assuming all of the files names actually end in ".csv" exactly. The `files` variable should have all three listed. > files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
> files
[1] "CopyOfdiamonds.csv" "diamonds.csv"      
>

Comment: All the files end in .csv as I've mentioned. Additionally, if I use the function `read.csv()` on one of the files which wasn't recognized by `files.list()`, I am able to read it in (and I use ".csv" when specifying the filename with `read.csv()` by the way). Therefore something else must be preventing this from working.

Comment: try just `list.files()` and see what is returned.

Comment: When I do this I see all the files, and I see that the difference between the file extensions is case (i.e. ".CSV" vs ".csv"). I guess I need to modify the regex accordingly with a "?i" somewhere?

Comment: The case matters.

Comment: `list.files` does have a parameter `ignore.case`, set that to `TRUE`

Comment: Have you tried the alternative `choose.files()`? It's meant to choose files interactively in Windows.

Comment: try this please files `files<- list.files(pattern=".*.csv")`

Comment: I had used the `ignore.case` and that did work. I'm curious as to why some of the file extensions were capitalized and some were not, but this detail was not displayed by the file type in windows explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the file extension for the file that worked was ".csv" and for the ones that didn't was ".CSV". I do not know how or why something like that can happen, but the `pattern` parameter of the `list.files` function is case sensitive.

Using the parameter setting `ignore.case = TRUE` solved this issue.